# Black diamond/questionmark replacing random characters in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My WordPress site was imported by creating CSV's in OpenOffice Calc, saving as Unicode (UTF-8) to preserve the Korean characters. The post contents imported without any major hiccups, but rendering on the front-end seems to have a problem.

Where I want to display the excerpt of the post limited to 200 characters, I am using this: -

```
<?php  
    $content = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());
    echo substr($content,0,200);
    echo '...';
?>
```

This should create something like this: -

```
some korean characters, pretend this is 200 characters...
```

Which it does, in around 50% of cases. In others, I get the dreaded black diamond with white question mark symbol just before the ellipsis.

However, if I do not use the strip_tags method, I would expect to see the diamon symbol in the same place - but I do not. Strangely, the posts where this does appear in the except, do not show the diamond symbol on the full post page.

Wp-config has 'DB_CHARSET' value 'utf8mb4'. The MySQL database tables and their columns show collation as 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'. Is this the problem? How could I rectify this?

When viewing the wp_posts table, I am not seeing the diamond symbol when I view the content of specific posts which seem to display this character in its excerpt.

Furthermore, if I edit a post which has this problem, and copy characters from around 190-210th character and paste at the beginning, I still only see the diamond symbol just before the ellipsis - which makes me think the strip_tags method is the problem.

Anyone care to try decipher this one?

Answer (score 0):

I always put the following in my .htaccess file.  I'm not sure how it works exactly, I found it somewhere online and it fixed issues for me so I just kept using it.

```
# USE UTF-8
php_value mbstring.language             neutral
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding    utf-8
php_value mbstring.encoding_translation on
php_value mbstring.http_input           auto
php_value mbstring.http_output          utf-8
php_value mbstring.detect_order         auto
php_value mbstring.substitute_character none
php_value default_charset               utf-8
```

I think I also had to add this at the very beginning of my code entry point:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

It's all Greek to me, but seems to solve my unicode worries.  Also, I ALWAYS make my mysql collations utf8_general_ci, every textual field.